# Spring-json problem in Liferay with Spring 2.5

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, liferay

I am trying to use the library spring-json.1.3.1 in a project that has been done with Liferay 5.1.2 which includes Spring 2.5.

Following the project website [instructions](http://spring-json.sourceforge.net/quick_interface.html), I managed to make the request hit in my controller, but at the moment of returning the json object back through the modelAndView object it fails with the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException at com.liferay.portlet.MimeResponseImpl.setContentType(MimeResponseImpl.java:162)
```

I have checked Liferays source code, and it checks that contentType that its being set is in a harcoded list,if it not it will throw a IllegalArgumentException that it is exactly what os happening.

This is my view resolver code:

```
<bean id="xmlFileViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.XmlViewResolver">
```

/WEB-INF/context/views.xml
     
     
         1

My views.xml code:

```
<beans>
   <bean name="jsonView" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.JsonView"/>
```

And my controller:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public ModelAndView handleRenderRequest(RenderRequest arg0,
   RenderResponse arg1) throws Exception {

   Map model = new HashMap();
         model.put("firstname", "Peter");
         model.put("secondname", "Schmitt");

   return new ModelAndView("jsonView", model);
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is because you need to set window state as exclusive mode, so it would work:

```
<portlet:renderURL var="jsonRequest" windowState="<%= LiferayWindowState.EXCLUSIVE.toString() %>"><portlet:param name="actionType" value="fetchGames"/></portlet:renderURL>
```

Piece of code from `MimeResponseImpl.java`:

```
public void setContentType(String contentType) {
    if (Validator.isNull(contentType)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }

    Enumeration<String> enu = _portletRequestImpl.getResponseContentTypes();

    boolean valid = false;

    if (getLifecycle().equals(PortletRequest.RESOURCE_PHASE) ||
        _portletRequestImpl.getWindowState().equals(
            LiferayWindowState.EXCLUSIVE)) {

        valid = true;
    }
```

Let me know if somebody need more help.

Comment: Thanks a lot, didn't see your answer before. But this works fine.